# I need help to write an essay about: probabilistic method || Occam's razor || mathematics in the 21st

Tags: probability, beginner, terminology

I am interested in one of the master's programs in Data Science. In the application process I need to submit an essay of 1,000 words about one of the following topics:

1. Drawbacks of the probabilistic method
2. A mathematical theory for Occam's razor
3. What drives mathematics in the 21st century?

I have a background in numerical analysis and I do not have any idea about how I can tackle these topics. I would like if someone familiar with one of these topics to give me pieces of advice, resources, or how the essay must be structured so can start writing the essay.

I appreciate your help, thank you in advance.

Comment: Topic 2) For a mathematical theory of Occam's razor see for example Information Theory and Minimum Description Length as guiding principles in machine learning and statistics

Comment: Topic 3) is somewhat opinion-based IMO although one would say Big data and AI are certainly on the rise. For Topic 1) I would need some clarification on what "probabilistic method" refers to

Comment: Is topic 1) about this [Probabilistic method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_method)?

Comment: Thank you for these insights. I’m not sure what they mean by “the probabilistic method” exactly. It is what is explained in the website you provided or what I have read in this post < https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/18000/117314> (bayesian networks, latent dirichlet … allocation, naive bayes model, probabilistic matrix factorization models)

Comment: can you tell me what IMO means ?

Comment: IMO = In My Opinion, IMHO =  In My Humble Opinion